# FFTW library: verifying fourier transform derivative property

Tags: c, signal-processing, fft, fftw

I am trying to verify this relation with the fftw library:

[image]

Therefore, I chose f to be a Gaussian, computed the Fourier Transform of its derivative and compared it with the one of the Fourier Transform of the Gaussian multiplied by ik. Here is what I get:

[image]

It is very strange, especially because the plot of the Fourier Transform of the derivative of the Gaussian (i.e the red one) is not 0 at the origin, while it should be (I checked with the analytic one).

The code seems ok to me, anyhow here it is (I am using C):

```
int main() {

    int i, N = 100;
    double v[N], x[N], k[N/2+1], vd[N];
    double dx = 2*pi/N, dk=2*pi/(N*dx), tmp;
    fftw_complex *out;
    fftw_plan forward,inverse;

    out = ( fftw_complex* )fftw_malloc( sizeof( fftw_complex )*( N/2 + 1 )); 


    forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, v, out, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    inverse = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, out, vd, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    //Initialise arrays 

    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {   
            x[i] = dx*i;
            v[i] = -2*x[i]*exp( -pow( x[i], 2) );

            printf( " %le %le \n ", x[i], v[i] );
    }  


    for( i = 0; i < N; i++ ) {
       k[i]=i*dk;
    }

    k[N/2]=0.;

    //Compute fft
    fftw_execute( forward ); 

    //Print the results

    for( i = 0; i < N/2 + 1 ; i++ ) {
        printf( "%le %le %le \n", i*dk, out[i][0], out[i][1] );
    }

    //Multiply by ik 

    for( i = 0; i < ( N/2 + 1 ); i++ ) {

            tmp=out[i][0];
            out[i][0]=-k[i]*out[i][1];
            out[i][1]=k[i]*tmp;

            printf( "%le %le %le \n", i*dk, out[i][0], out[i][1] );

    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(forward);
    fftw_destroy_plan(inverse);
    fftw_free(out);

    return 0;  
}
```

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the (relevant) code directly in your question, not links to images of code.

Comment: Note that whilst that relationship holds for the Fourier Transform, it isn't quite that straightforward for the Discrete Fourier Transform.

Comment: Yes, in principle you are right, but I checked (for example here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node2.html ) and it should still be valid.

Comment: That doesn't mention DFT at all.

Comment: Sorry, wrong link, I meant here: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e101/lectures/handout3/node7.html

Comment: One obvious bug is that `k` only has size `N/2+1`, yet you initialise it as if it had size `N` (`N` should probably `N/2` in your `for` loop.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The discretized signal of the derived gaussian is supposed to be:

```
        x[i] = dx*i;
        v[i] = -2*x[i]*exp( -pow( x[i], 2) );
```

Nevertheless, the Discrete Fourier Transform corresponds to the Fourier Transform of **periodic** signals. Indeed, the underlining discretized function is written as an infinite weighted sum of sine waves.

Therefore, as DFT is applied, the discretized signal above corresponds to a periodized half of the derivative of a gaussian. Indeed, its average (zero frequency) is not zero, as all the values are negative.

To mimic the derivative of a gaussian (or any other signal of "finite" range ), the whole range of the signal must be covered. Hence, `dx` must be chosen such that `dx*N>>sigma`, where `sigma` is the standard deviation of the gaussian. And all the support of the function must be covered, including the positive side of the derivative.

Could you try something like:

```
        double sigma=dx*N*0.1;
        x[i] = dx*i-dx*(N/2);
        v[i] = -2*x[i]*exp( -pow( x[i]/sigma, 2) );
```

There must be a scaling left due to the value of the standard deviation.

The DFT can still be useful for non-periodic function, but the non-periodic functions are to be mapped to a periodic function by using a [window](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function). What is observed here is that applying a rectangular window, periodizing and then deriving is not the same as deriving, applying a rectangular window and finally periodizing. While all linear, these operators do not commute!

Comment: Setting `sigma=dx=1` should be fine, makes the computations easier. I get a nice DFT out of that.

Comment: I agree with you about  the periodicity argument, indeed I should transform a function which has the same values at the extremes of the "box". The problem is that, as far as I understood, FFTW works in such a way that the first element of the output array is associated with the origin of frequencies, so whenever I transform a signal which is not starting from the origin, I get problems ( by the way if you knew ho to solve that it would be great). I tried with a gaussian which starts from the origin and is centered in the half of the box, but still those plots are very different.

Comment: @Mike : Indeed, this is the idea behind more refined window than the rectangular one. Most windows features values going to zero near the edges so as to recover a continuous periodized signal and avoid introducing an artificial discontinuity which pollutes the estimate of the derivative. In fact, some windows feature a null derivative at the edge so that even the first derivative of the periodized signal remain smooth. You can try to apply a Tukey window!

Comment: @MikeM: You don't need a windowing function here. You need to make sure that the full Gaussian is in your `v[i]`, with the origin at `v[0]`, and with `v[i]` periodic: `v[i+size]` should be filled for `i` from `-1` to `-size/2`. This way you can fit your whole kernel in the signal, and still have the origin where it needs to be for the DFT. If `v` is large enough, the Gaussian will not introduce any discontinuities anywhere.